# Convert Image to Uint8List in Flutter without using Dart:ui

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-ui

I need to convert Image to Uint8List in Flutter without using Dart:ui because this lib crashes while app is in the background,

this code works for dart:ui and I don't want that because my app crashes on **image.toByteData()**, [explained why on flutter github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135245#issuecomment-1756180401)

```
var img = await loadImageFromUrl(event.imgUrl);
final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
final picCanvas = Canvas(recorder);
var painter = BoxPainter(img, boxes);
painter.paint(picCanvas, size);
picture = recorder.endRecording(); 
final image = picture.toImageSync(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt());
final data = await image.toByteData();
final result = data.buffer.asUint8List();
```

**I need a different approach**, maybe with image library?

Comment: How did you create this `image` in the first place? With `instantiateImageCodec`, for example?

Comment: @RichardHeap
final picture = recorder.endRecording();
final image = picture.toImageSync(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt());
final data = await image.toByteData();
final result = data.buffer.asUint8List();

Comment: Yes, it seems like image may be your best option. You can load the source file, manipulate the pixels and save.

Comment: @RichardHeap i see you are some pro guy in flutter, could you look at that topic? it's similar one but I am a bit stuck with package:image.dart ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77411711/how-to-convert-uint8list-to-png-in-dart-using-packageimage-dart-and-manipulate